# Error Message From Excel Macro - Copy from one cell to another

Tags: excel

I got the error message "runtime error '1004' "We can't do that to a merged cell."  when I was using the following code:

```
Sub CBCR71Out_Click()
   If ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("CBCR71Out").Value = 1 Then
      Sheets("7 ELA").Range("CR71Out").Copy _
        Destination:=Worksheets("7 ELA Output").Range("CR7.1")
   Else
      Sheets("7 ELA Output").Range("CR7.1").Value = ""
   End If
End Sub
```

I am creating an Excel workbook where users select info on one worksheet and it is copied to a second sheet and put into a print friendly format.  This particular piece of info goes from 1 cell on the original sheet to a merged 3-cell title on the output sheet.

I'm learning as I go, so I don't know what to do here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure how to do this the way you have, but you could probably change this code:

```
 Sheets("7 ELA").Range("CR71Out").Copy _
   Destination:=Worksheets("7 ELA Output").Range("CR7.1")
```

to this code:

```
Sheets("7 ELA Output").Range("CR7.1").Value = Sheets("7 ELA").Range("CR71Out").Value
```

Essentially putting the value to be copied into the print friendly one.

Comment: Thank you for your response Shauno. That does work, but I found in my earlier work on this project that the code suggested does not copy formatting.  If there is no way around this I could use the above code and change the overall formatting of the destination cell...though I would like to avoid this.

Comment: Hi Paul, I thought the idea was to not copy formatting? If you have the destination sheet all setup in a print friendly format, then I assume you just need to plug values in and print away? Which is why I avoided copying the data. You might need to specify the data being copied and the format it is in pre and post copy?

Comment: The issue I am running up against is that in some of the data being copied over in a cell is bolded, but not the entire content.  If there is nothing I can do about that I will just Bold all the content on the destination formatting.

Comment: I see, that's quite an important factor, probably something you should mention in your questions for future reference... what's the format of the cell? Will it change? Have a look at this page and see if it helps you http://www.excel-pratique.com/en/vba_tricks/format_characters_in_a_cell.php